# fastest update with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that it took days to be executed

```
DECLARE @cnt BIGINT
SET @cnt = 1

WHILE @cnt * 1000 < 92746339
BEGIN

    UPDATE TOP (1000) [dbo].[Vente]
    SET Promo =
        CASE
            WHEN [Code Article] IN (
                    SELECT [Code Article]
                    FROM [Promotion]
                    WHERE datecol BETWEEN [Date Debut Promo] AND [Date Fin Promo]
                )
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END

    WHERE promo IS NULL
    PRINT '@cnt: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @cnt)
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END
```

Number of rows : Vente = 92 millions and promotion =419187
The execution plan :

[image]

How to make it faster ?

Comment: are updating 92 million rows?

Comment: How fast do you need that to be?

Comment: About four or three hours

Comment: Relations between tables 1-to-1 ?

Comment: It is an index seek already. You can play with portions and `Maximum Degree of Parallelism`. Search for it. I don't think there is anything else here to optimize.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri what do you mean about Maximum Degree of Parallelism ?

Comment: @testtest, I mean google it...

Comment: Instead of 1000 at a time, try 50000 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a `JOIN` instead `IN` clause ?

```
UPDATE v
    SET v.Promo = CASE 
                     WHEN p.[Code Article] IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                     ELSE 0
                  END
FROM [dbo].[Vente] v
LEFT JOIN [Promotion] p
    ON v.[Code Article] = p.[Code Article]
       AND (datecol between [Date Debut Promo] AND [Date Fin Promo])
WHERE v.Promo IS NULL;
```

How many rows in your tables ?

Comment: Vente = 92 millions and promotion =419187